# JQuery taking one attribute from data

Tags: jquery

I couldn't catch attribute from

```
data-smth="{containment:'.video-section', quality:'large', mute:true, opacity:1}"
```

i want take mute and change to false. 
How can I do this? For data with one attribute it's works.

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
$('.selector').attr("data-smth","{containment:'.video-section', quality:'large', mute:false, opacity:1}");
```

Here's the documentation:http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: glad to help. Plz mark my ans if you satisfy @ Grisza

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you read this attribute of data-smth using .attr() in jquery the return value is always a String.

So in order to change mute to false what you would need to do is use jQuery.parseJSON() function. However you will also need to format you attribute data-smth to be proper JSON.

Ive made a plunker here with how i did it

```
<h1 id="title" data-smth='{"containment":".video-section", "quality":"large", "mute":true, "opacity":1}'>Hello Plunker!</h1>


$( document ).ready(function() {
    var x = $('#title').attr('data-smth');
    console.log(x);
    var y = jQuery.parseJSON(x);
    console.log(y);
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/O7u1p7WuB9PO7tLmYA9Y

Once you have the variable as a JSON object you can use y.mute = false; and then save y back to the attribute using .attr();